# my soundmanager(avaudioplayer) is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, avaudioplayer, soundmanager2

Im programming an AVAudioPlayer its not working :(, heres my code:
speacially last secsion says to me there have some problem**

```
    private func playerForFile(fileName: String) -> AVAudioPlayer {
        if let existingPlayer = soundPlayers[fileName] {
            return existingPlayer
        }
        let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: nil)

        let newPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil)
        soundPlayers[fileName] = newPlayer
        return newPlayer
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you you mean by "not working" exactly? do you get error output/log output?

Comment: so,  in this " let newPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL, error: nil) "   secsion ,i have expected expression error. I changed this secsion like this "let newPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL!,fileTypeHint: nil); throws"  but still i have problem

Comment: how about `let newPlayer = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: fileURL!)`?

Comment: Thanks. It's working finaly :)